# Extract data out of a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, coding-style

I am trying to extract data out of a csv file and output the data to another csv file.

```
relate task perform     
0   avc asd     
1   12  24      
2   34  54      
3   22  33      
4   11  11      
5   335 534     
Time    A   B   C   D
0   0.334   0.334   0.334   0.334
1   0.543   0.543   0.543   0.543
2   0.752   0.752   0.752   0.752
3   0.961   0.961   0.961   0.961
4   1.17    1.17    1.17    1.17
5   1.379   1.379   1.379   1.379
```

I am writing a python script to read the above table. I want all the data from Time, A, B,C, and D onwards in a separate file.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os

read_file = False


with open ('xyz.csv', mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f_read:
reader = csv.reader(f_read)

for row in reader:
    if 'Time' in row
```

I am stuck here. I read all the data in 'reader'. All the rows should have been parsed inside 'reader'. Now, how can I extract the data from line with Time and onwards into a separate file?

Is there a better method to achieve the above objective?
Should I use pandas instead of regular python commands?

I read many similar answers on stackoverflow but I am confused on how to finish this problem. Your help is appreciated.

Best

Comment: As you already stated this has been answered a million times. You'll have to explain what exactly is not answered in the million existing posts.

Comment: Copying from one file to another is mentioned. However, you can see the numbers of columns change mid-data. So, how can I extract that information? Also, I was hoping for explanation with the solution. Usually, I just find a solution. I thought may be I can get multiple ways of solving this problem. I am stuck at operations to manipulate row. Thanks!